# PHP Array / Multidimensional / Dynamic Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array from an xml file as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1280
    [1] => 1281
    [2] => 1282
)
```

I have a second array of numbers that should be linked to the above array.

For example

```
1280 links to 0001, 0002, 0003
1281 links to 5000
1282 links to 3001, 2424
```

What is the best approach to link/associate the values in these two arrays?

All the values above are dynamic from XML and can be different any at time.

I think what I need is something like:

```
Array
(
    [1280] => Array
       (
           [0] => 0001
           [1] => 0002
           [2] => 0003
       )

    [1281] => Array
       (
           [0] => 5000
       )

    [1282] => Array
       (
           [0] => 3001
           [1] => 2424
       )
)
```

and then loop through each array by 1280, 1281, 1282.

all values are provided from an XML file. There's at least 1 but can be as many as 100.

1280, 1281, 1282 are fitness classes and they are associated to a fitness instructor.  All values are unique.

I can get the following:

1280, 0001
1280, 0002
1280, 0003
1281, 3000
etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

I am able to get the values in one array as such:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1280|0001
    [1] => 1280|0002
    [2] => 1280|0003 
    [3] => 1281|5000
    [4] => 1282|3001
    [5] => 1282|2424 
)
```

Comment: where do the values `1280, 1281, 1282` come from? We need a bit more

Comment: all values are provided from an XML file. There's at least 1 but can be as many as 100.

Comment: yeah but we need to know how you programatically get those values.  If you want to create an algorithm to merge the values, we need to know how they relate.

Comment: 1280, 1281, 1282 are fitness classes and they are associated to a fitness instructor.  All values are unique.

Comment: how does 1280 'link' to `0001, 0002, 0003`? show us the xml where they are defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the values in arrays are integers and by the example of code that you want to get, this should do the trick.

```
$array1 = array(1280, 1281, 1282);
$array2 = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(5000), array(3001, 2424));
$result = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $array1.size(); $i++) {
    $result[$array1[$i]] = $array2[$i];
}
```